# Input values empty after computed property triggers

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem in a Vue js project.
I have a computed property called total, this property when gets triggered, make  a sum of a property monto on an array called cobrosMarcados which get filled after I click a checkbox of the cobros array. The real problem is that I have 2 input date-rangepicker linked to a Vue component data variables, but when the computed property gets triggered, the input values from the date-rangepicker get reset and the values are empty.

This is the Vue js code

```
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     cobros: [
        {id:1,nombre:"Mantenimiento",monto:2000},
        {id:2,nombre:"Piscina",monto:2000},
        {id:3,nombre:"Seguridad",monto:2000},
     ],
     cobrosMarcados: [],
     montoPagado: 0,
     vueltoNegativo: false,
     fechaInicial: '',
     fechaFinal: ''
   },
   computed:{
        total(){
            return this.cobrosMarcados.reduce((total, item) => {
                return total + Number(item.monto);
            }, 0);
        },
        vuelto(){
            let vuelto = this.montoPagado - this.total;
            this.vueltoNegativo = vuelto < 0;
            return vuelto;
        }
    },
    methods:{
        addCobro(index){

            let item = this.cobros.find(o => o.id === index);
            let found = false;

            for (let i = 0; i < this.cobrosMarcados.length; i++) {
                if(this.cobrosMarcados[i].id === item.id){
                    found = true;
                    this.cobrosMarcados.splice(i,1);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!found){
                this.cobrosMarcados.push({
                    id: item.id,
                    nombre: item.nombre,
                    monto: item.monto
                });
            }
        }
    }
  })
```

Here is the link the code
https://jsfiddle.net/alonsourena/syLrqekm/

Hope someone can help me

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these elements are `input` elements, you should be use `v-model` instead of `v-bind`.

e.g. `<input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="fechaInicial" name="fechaInicial" v-model="fechaInicial"/>`

See more: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model

**EDIT**: There was a second problem you identified -- the datepicker component you're using doesn't play nicely with Vue.

You can solve it by a) using a different date picker, or b) using `v-on:blur` instead of `v-model` and writing a function that updates the values manually.

See example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bth9j8

Comment: Thanks for helping but still having the same issue. Here is the new code https://jsfiddle.net/syLrqekm/8/

Comment: Hmm... the values aren't being reset for me. These are the `fechaInicial` and `fechaFinal` values you're talking about, yeah?

Comment: Yeah you right. The values on the Vue component are the same. The problem is with the date-rangepicker, it empty the values on the input field. Thanks

Comment: Yes it works, seems that the problem is with the library im using for the daterangepicker. Im using boostrap datepicker.

Comment: This one shows the exact error I'm getting on my project. Select a date and then check some cobro option. You should see how the input value resets https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jcldh8?file=index.js

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right. Looks like that datepicker is setting the value without firing the `input` or `change` events (which is what vue listens to). You can fudge it by using `v-on:blur="setDate"` and then defining a setDate method. I put an example in my answer.

Comment: Thak you so much for helping me, I really appreciate it with this.v-blur helps but it does not do all I need so i think im going to uso another library. Do you know some one where I can use range of months without showing the day?

Comment: If you haven't found one already, take a look at [vuejs-datepicker](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker). It has a 'month-view only' mode.

Comment: Thanks MynockSpit, I already find the solution, but that library seems to have what I need.